# Relative velocity decomposition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, atmospheric-science

In my fluid dynamics course notes is stated a change in relative velocity can be decomposed:

$$\delta \mathbf{v} =
\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
\Delta & 0 \\
0 & \Delta 
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
D_1 & D_2 \\
D_2 & -D_1
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\xi \\
\xi & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\delta x \\
\delta y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $
\Delta = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},
D_1 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},
D_2 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x},
\xi = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

I haven't been able to find a reference to this online.  Does this decomposition have a name?  How is it derived?

Comment: Could you check the definition of $D_2$? It should be $D_2 = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Comment: @user23660 Fixed, thanks.  I've since found a couple of references to this.  It might be called a velocity gradient tensor, and there's [some information about deformation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(meteorology))

Answer (score 3):

**Matrices**

It's a general property of square matrices (and 2-tensors). Any matrix $M_{ij}$ can be decomposed into a part containing the trace, and a part that is traceless. 
So we begin 
$$M_{ij} = \frac{1}{N} (\operatorname{tr} M) \delta_{ij} + \left( M_{ij} - \frac{1}{N} (\operatorname{tr} M) \delta_{ij}\right)$$

I hope that much is evident. The first part contains the trace, and the second part is traceless. I've just shuffled things around.

Now, the second and third terms we'll call $R$, which is traceless by construction. You can further decompose it into a symmetric and anti-symmetric part:
$$R_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \left( R_{ij} + R_{ji} \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left( R_{ij} - R_{ji} \right)$$

The reason for decomposing matrices in such a way is that the various bits don't mix under coordinate transformations (rotations).

**Vector fields**

I should also add that a vector field can be decomposed into a rotational (curl) and irrotational (divergence of a scalar) part ([proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition)). In 2 dimensions this is handy because we can use a lot of tools from complex analysis.

**Addendum**

I forgot to add that the reason for a matrix is just the chain rule:
$$\delta v = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \delta x + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \delta y$$
$$\delta u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \delta x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \delta y$$

Answer (score 2):

I believe this decomposition has a specific name "Cauchy–Helmholtz theorem (regarding the decomposition of the velocity of a point within an infinitesimal continuum particle)".

You can read about this decomposition in the wikipedia page on [Strain rate tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_rate_tensor), sections about symmetric and antisymmetric parts and shear rate and compression rate (though this name has not been used). Note, that some formulas there require adaptation from 3D to 2D.